# Scrolling down: Header bar show and hide

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hello I seem to have some issues regarding my view controller. When the user scrolls down my header bar will slowly fade out, once the user scroll up the header bar will slowly fade back in. My issue is when scrolling down and up the header bar sometimes gets stuck and becomes choppy, like this image:

[image: Header bar fading]
[image]

[image]

The white bar gets stuck without having a clean appear and disappear effect. Here is the code:

```
    #warning new code for hide header bar
/**
 *  Catch scroll event for calculating Show and hide header view
 * Note that _menu (tableView) is the scrollable control
 */
[_contentTableView addObserver:self
        forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"
           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
           context:nil];
_hidesBarsOnScroll = YES;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context
{
UITableView *tempTableView = _contentTableView;

CGPoint oldOffset = [(NSValue *)change[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] CGPointValue];

if (!_hidesBarsOnScroll || tempTableView.contentOffset.y == oldOffset.y)
    return;

// Show on scroll up
if (_barsHidden &&
    tempTableView.contentOffset.y < oldOffset.y &&
    tempTableView.contentOffset.y + tempTableView.bounds.size.height < tempTableView.contentSize.height) // Skip on bottom
{

    if (tempTableView.contentOffset.y < 60) {
        _header.hidden = NO;
        float alpha = 1.0 - tempTableView.contentOffset.y / 64.0;
        [_header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.1216 green: 0.1569 blue: 0.2078 alpha: alpha]];
    }
    if (tempTableView.contentOffset.y<=0)
    {
        CGRect contentViewFrame = _contentTableView.frame;
        contentViewFrame.origin.y = 64;
        _contentTableView.frame = contentViewFrame;

        [_header setBackgroundColor:_headerColor];
        _barsHidden = NO;
    }
}

// Hide on scroll down
if (!_barsHidden &&
    tempTableView.contentOffset.y > 0 && // Skip on top
    tempTableView.contentOffset.y > oldOffset.y)
{
    float alpha = 1.0 - tempTableView.contentOffset.y / 64.0;
    [_header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.1216 green:     0.1569 blue: 0.2078 alpha: alpha]];

    CGRect contentViewFrame = _contentTableView.frame;
    contentViewFrame.origin.y = 84-tempTableView.contentOffset.y;
    _contentTableView.frame = contentViewFrame;

    if (tempTableView.contentOffset.y >= 64) {
        _barsHidden = YES;
        _header.hidden = YES;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView inherits the UIScrollView delegate, so keeping track of the content offset can be simplified as follows...

```
// in the view controller
self.contentTableView.delegate = self;
```

Then implement

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.contentTableView) {
        // header logic
        self.header = [self alphaAtOffset:scrollView.contentOffset.y];
    }
}
```

The next part of the problem is to produce a function mapping scroll position to header alpha.  The domain of this function should be any float, and the range should be 0.0 to 1.0.

I can't tell exactly what you're going for from your code, but typically a function like this looks like:

```
                    SOME_THRESHOLD
                          |
                          v
alpha == 1  ----------|
                      |\
                      | \
                      |  \--------- alpha == 0
                      |
 neg contentOffset.y  |  pos contentOffset.y
```

where SOME_THRESHOLD is  the scrolling offset where you wish the header to disappear entirely.  This can be rendered in code as follows...

```
#define SOME_THRESHOLD 64.0

- (CGFloat)alphaAtOffset:(CGFloat)offset {
    if (offset < 0.0) return 1.0;
    if (offset > SOME_THRESHOLD) return 0.0;
    return 1.0 - (offset / SOME_THRESHOLD);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, much appreciated! Did I overload myself and overdo the code when I can simplify it?

Comment: I think so.  I think the code I suggest is all that's needed.